# route confusion in laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

i am working on the project in which i have two route like

```
Route::get('project/{id}',          [ 'as'=>'add_project_info.project' , 'uses'=>'ProjectController@add_project_info']);
Route::get('project/notes/',    ['as'=>'notes.project','uses'=>'NotesController@index']);
```

now the thing is when i call "project/notes/" in url then it redirect to "project/{id}" .laravel assume the "notes" as the "id" of the first route. when i shuffle the route like

```
Route::get('project/notes/',    ['as'=>'notes.project','uses'=>'NotesController@index']);
Route::get('project/{id}',          [ 'as'=>'add_project_info.project' , 'uses'=>'ProjectController@add_project_info']);
```

then its perfectly working.please suggest me some better way to solve this ,thanku

Answer (score 0):

It's just how it works. Laravel will use the first suitable route for given URI. So, the only way to make it work is to change routes order like this:

```
Route::get('project/notes/', ['as' => 'notes.project', 'uses' => 'NotesController@index']);
Route::get('project/{id}', ['as' => 'add_project_info.project', 'uses' => 'ProjectController@add_project_info']);
```

Comment: is this the only way for this?

Comment: @SandeepSingh this is the only right way to do that. Is there any reason why don't you like it?

Comment: #Alexey Mezenin no no sir there is not any specific reason, i just want to know for any other way to do this,by the way thank you very much sir.